# Why can't I access a variable declared in a switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement, global-variables

this is my code :
there is a probléme "can't acces to variable j"

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
    char digit = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
        switch (digit){ 
            case 'x' : { int j = 0; System.out.println(j); } 
            default : { int j = 100; System.out.println(j); }

        }
    }
    int i = j;
    System.out.println(i); 
}
```

Comment: Why exactly have you used `switch-case` here? You're not even modifying `digit` in your loop.

Comment: Something to be aware of - if you don't put a `break;` statement at the end of each `case` of your switch, then the next `case` will get executed too.  In this example, if `digit` were to be `'x'`, you'd get both `0` and `100` printed out.

Answer (score 3):

Each variable has scope. Scope is a restriction regarding where some variable can be accessed.

When you **declare** a variable in any type of block `{}`, that variable can only be accessed within that block of code.

You'll have to declare (and possibly initialize) the variable outside the block so its scope is greater, either at the method level or as a `static` variable (or instance if you were working with instance methods).